# Mapbox iOS SDK use multiple files

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox-ios

I wanted to code a map app for personal use (iOS) using swift 5. I have already been able to make it working by using a single file, but the code looks like a mess, so I decided to use multiple files and just call functions from the ViewController.
For a simple map view I already made it possible with this code:

```
//ViewController.swift
import UIKit
import Mapbox
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapInit()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
}
```

```
//mapInit.swift
import Foundation
import Mapbox
extension ViewController{
    func mapInit(){
        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
         
        // Set the map’s center coordinate and zoom level.
        mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 59.31, longitude: 18.06), zoomLevel: 9, animated: false)
        view.addSubview(mapView)
    }
}
```

but I tried to change the map style from the ViewController file using

```
mapView.styleURL = MGLStyle.darkStyleURL
```

but I got

```
Use of unresolved identifier mapView
```

I also tried to use

```
self.mapView.styleURL = MGLStyle.darkStyleURL
```

but now I got

```
Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'mapView'
```

I also tried to add

```
var mapView: MGLMapView!
```

at the top of the ViewController
but now it crashes with the message

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

Finally I tried to initialize the mapView from the ViewController.swift and change the style from the mapInit() but it changed nothing.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you add this

```
import Mapbox
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {
var mapView: MGLMapView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0), zoomLevel: 5, animated: false)
mapView.delegate = self
view.addSubview(mapView)
```

to your main ViewController, then you can access the mapview via an `extension ViewController`.